# Implementation if condition in z3

Tags: z3, smt

I am facing problem implementing verilog if condition in z3.

```
if(reset == 1){
  G5 <= 0;
} else {
  G5 <= G10;
}
```

I am trying to implement above code using ofollowing code in z3 smt.

```
s.add( (BoolExpr) ctx.mkITE( ctx.mkEq(reset,ctx.mkNumeral("1",ctx.mkBitVecSort(1))) , ctx.mkEq(G5,ctx.mkNumeral("0",ctx.mkBitVecSort(1))) , ctx.mkEq(G5,G10) ));
s.add( ctx.mkEq(reset,ctx.mkNumeral("1",ctx.mkBitVecSort(1))) );
```

While executing above step i am not able to control reset( i want G5<=G10 as solution). For example if i am trying to give reset as '0' for execution i am getting error as "invalid usage". because i am trying to constraint reset twice.

Please help me with above issue.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Please help me with above issue.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly the problem is and what you want to achieve? Do you actually want the string "G5<=G10" to be returned as the "solution"? Also, there is no way to "control" reset, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I am so sorry actually i was not declaring variable coorectly. I figured it out just now.